# Breaking while importing Stocker in python

Tags: python

Please advise me on the below mentioned break, what is this break and how to resolve it.

> from stocker import Stocker

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/aryabhatta/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
    from stocker import Stocker

File "/home/aryabhatta/stocker.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2):

Your file has the same name as the `stocker` module. Change `stocker.py` to something else and it will work.

Comment: No impact at all.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the concrete first few lines of your code?

Comment: I am just trying to import Stocker library as per reference of this link(https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/b26ac7af70b0aee94daff86794f15b1f20a5b11d/stocker). However, I have fulfilled the requirement, still I am not able to import library of Stocker. Please assist me accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line below :

**`from Stocker.stocker import Stocker`**